# Microsoft F# issues when rebuilding the projects

Tags: visual-studio-2013, f#, project

I'm getting the following error when I run my F# project.
"Error  98  "fsc.exe" exited with code -1073741571. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.1\Framework\v4.0\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets    155 9   "

I got this error after installing windows 10
I used to have this F# project on windows 8.1 and the project was running fine but after I upgraded to windows 10, I'm getting this error. My environment is Visual Studio 2013.

I reinstalled vs2013 however I still get this error

Answer (score 1):

Might be worth installing the latest and greatest version of F# to make sure that everything is in the right place.

1. Make sure that you have the [Windows 10 and .NET 4.6 SDK](https://dev.windows.com/en-US/downloads/windows-10-sdk) installed from Microsoft. You can download the SDK and install it standalone if you're not sure you have everything.
2. Install [Visual F# Tools 4.0 RTM](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48179).

Comment: I tried that but did not help. It's something with F# complier (fsc.exe) and windows 10. I even tried using vs-2015 I have the same error